# PySimpleGUI align rows on different columns

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

Being new to python and python GUI's I started using PySimpleGUI.
So I got a database with image attributes (from OCR) and I want to make a kind of image gallery that shows a list of the image attributes by the side of each image and allows de attributes to be updated. (The text in the prints will be turned into text boxes for input). **The attributes list should be vertically centered to its image.**

I got:
[image: Current GUI layout]

And I want something like:
[image]

I've been trying to play around with different containers (that's why I got frames there), their 'vertical_alignment' and 'size' attributes. But no luck so far.

In the end, I'll do a list or grid with pagination to load all the images but this is the base structure/module to do it.

Here's the code I have:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

def get_img_data(f, first=False):
    """Generate image data using PIL
    """
    img = Image.open(f)
    img = img.resize((200,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    if first:                     # tkinter is inactive the first time
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(bio, format="PNG")
        del img
        return bio.getvalue()
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

#load images into elements
image_elem1 = sg.Image(data=get_img_data('img_edit/img_1.jpg', first=True))
image_elem2 = sg.Image(data=get_img_data('img_edit/img_2.jpg', first=True))

#img 1 attributes list
col_21 =[
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ]]

#img 2 attributes list
col_22 =[
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ]]

#images column
col_1 = [
        [image_elem1],
        [image_elem2]
        ]

#attributes column
col_2 = [
        [sg.Frame(layout=[[sg.Column(col_21, vertical_alignment = 'c')]], vertical_alignment = 'c',title='')],
        [sg.Frame(layout=[[sg.Column(col_22, vertical_alignment = 'c')]], vertical_alignment = 'c',title='')]]

layout = [[sg.Column(col_1), sg.Column(col_2)]]
# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, resizable=True)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should layout row by row, not column by column:

```py
#load images into elements
image_elem1 = sg.Image(data=get_img_data('img_edit/img_1.jpg', first=True))
image_elem2 = sg.Image(data=get_img_data('img_edit/img_2.jpg', first=True))

#img 1 attributes list
col_21 =[
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   1   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ]]

#img 2 attributes list
col_22 =[
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ],
        [sg.Text('Image   2   attribute    item    '), sg.Button(button_text="Update") ]]

layout = [[image_elem1, sg.Frame(layout=col_21, title='')],
          [image_elem2, sg.Frame(layout=col_22, title='')]]
```

Comment: Thanks, damn the layout basics... was really blocked :p